# .flatMap() Thread Getting Stuck

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"))
        .flatMap(a -> Mono.just(a).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
        .doOnNext(
            a ->
                System.out.println(
                    "Receivedededed " + a + " on thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .flatMap(
            a -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "Received: " + a + " on threads: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
              if ("a" == a) return getCreditScore(a);
              else return Mono.just(a);
            })
        .subscribe(a -> System.out.println("afka" + a));

    System.out.println("Main Thread Free");

    try {
      Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am getting the below output:

```
Receivedededed a on thread:parallel-1
Received: a on threads: parallel-1
Main Thread Free
```

And then infinite waiting

Where `getCreditScore(a)` has a thread that waits infinitely.

Now, as I understand it, `flatMap` subscribes to all the inner streams eagerly and does not wait for one to complete before subscribing to another. Since I have used `.subscribeOn()`, the first `flatMap` emits events on two different threads. The second `flatMap` should subscribe to the event corresponding to "b" and "c" as even though the thread containing "a" is waiting, the rest of the threads are free and `flatMap` does not waiting for a stream to finish before subscribing to another.

The debugger shows `parallel-1` in sleeping state (which is correct as `getCreditScore(a)` makes the thread sleep indefinitely) and `parallel-2` and `parallel-3` in wait state.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because every operator processes items within it one at a time. That is the crux of reactive.
In your processing logic, since you are blocking the thread indefinitely, the other items ("b", "c") are just queued up and never processed.
"a" of course is pushed to the queue first because `Flux. fromIterable` is executed in a sequential manner.

Instead of explicitly taking control over threads, use `Mono.delay` to return a "promise" instead. This will ensure "b" and "c" are printed

Comment: Dang got it. I was making the thread sleep in getCreditScore(a) to emulate a long running process. Should have returned a delayed Mono or something. Thanks.

Comment: FYI tools like https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound will help identifying blocking operations in non-blocking threads and throw and error if you do something you should not be doing :)